How to bind an optional property in QML?
I'm developping a QtQuick Custom Style (according too this documentation), and I'm facing a problem.
My Button template implementation expose an additionnal user property
MyCustomStyle/Button.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Templates as T

T.Button {
    id: control

    enum ButtonVariations {
        Giant,
        Regular,
        Small
    }

    property int variation : Button.ButtonVariations.Regular

    //...
}

The problem is that when I use a Button in my application, it will load either this Button template definition, or another one, depending on the style choosen for the app.
This result in an error in qml
MyApp/SomePage.qml
    ComboBox {
        id: comboBox
        width: 140
        height: 25

        model: ["Giant", "Regular", "Small"]
    }

    Button {
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignTop
        text: "Normal"
        implicitWidth: 100

        variation : comboBox.currentIndex    //error : Invalid property name "variation" (M16)
    }

When I run the app, it works great, and the button reacts according to the property. But due to this error, Qt Design Studio cannot parse the file, and cannot adapt views.

Question : Is it possible to assign this property as an "optionnal" property in QML ?

I've already tried this, unsuccesfully :
1 - Check if property exists (according to this topic)
    variation ? variation : comboBox.currentIndex //Do not works

-> this syntax doesn't seems to exists
2 - Re-declare property in the instantiation (so it could overrides or first-declare the property)
Button {
    id: myButton

    property int variation : comboBox.currentIndex //Do not works
}

-> This compile and doesn't generate error, but it's like if the property inside the T.Button isn't binded anymore. Nothing reacts
EDIT :
3 - Try to use a simple Binding type as follow (thanks to smr's comment)
Binding {
    variation: comboBox.currentIndex
}

-> Generate an error at runtime. Component cannot be loaded

How about using Binding component?

Thanks, this what I was looking for ! I achieved to make it works with following code :
Binding { when: button2.variation !== "undefined"; button2.variation: comboBox.currentIndex}. I tried to write it without id, or at least using parent if Binding is child of the Button, but without success.
Could I let you put this code snippet as an answer, so I could accept it

I'm currently unable to reproduce the exact condition because the problem occurs in Qt Design Studio. What I've tried is removing the defined variable (by commenting it out) to make it work.
Meanwhile, @iam_peter has suggested a method of initializing the property inside Component.onCompleted.
Also, there's an alternative approach using Binding; when you need to initialize a component in a delayed mode or when a specific condition is met.
Since Qt 6.*, there are three ways to use Binding, but in two of these methods, the variable must exist at parse time, and one is checked at runtime.
Currently, I'm unsure how to reproduce a condition where the component has the property at parse time but not at runtime.
* Based on this, I think that if Binding { when: button.variation !== undefined; button.variation: comboBox.currentIndex } works, then Binding { button.variation: comboBox.currentIndex } should also work.
The following is the code that I have tried:
component Button: T.Button {
    // property int variation: 0
    text: "Text " + (this.variation ?? "")
}

Row {   
    Button { 
        // Run-time checking, no Error
        id: button1
        Binding {
            when: Object(button1).hasOwnProperty('variation')
            target: button1; property: 'variation'; value: 1
        }
    }

    Button { 
        // Parse-time checking
        // Error, if `variation` is not defined while parsing the file.
        id: button2
        Binding on variation {
            value: 2
            when: Object(button2).hasOwnProperty('variation')
        }
    }

    Button { 
        // Parse-time checking
        // Error, if `variation` is not defined while parsing the file.
        id: button3
        Binding {
            target: button3; property: 'variation'; value: 3
            when: Object(button3).hasOwnProperty('variation')
        }
    }
}


You are right ! Binding { button.variation: comboBox.currentIndex } is sufficient for parsing, but generate an error at runtime (if variation is not defined). It's the same when I add when: button.variation !== "undefined".
I've tried a mix between your first example, and mine : Binding {when: Object(button).hasOwnProperty('variation'); button.variation: comboBox.currentIndex }, but this doesn't works at runtime too.
Your first example (button1), and @iam_peter solutions works both. I prefer yours, for its readability. Thanks for your help.

Edit : @iam_peter solution generate a warning at runtime : Warning: file:///C:/Users/[...]/PushButtonPage.qml:57: Error: Cannot assign to non-existent property "variation". But it still allow app to display the component

@LucasTerrier, something isn't right with @iam_peter's code, which I just noticed: AFAIK, undefined === "undefined" are not equal. "undefined" is a string and shouldn't be equal to undefined, which is a JavaScript primitive. Maybe the warning goes away if you use undefined or Object(...).hasOwnProperty('variation'), which is the best fit for checking whether a property exists or not.

You could something like this. Have a property that checks if variation is defined and if that is the case assign a binding to it in the Component.onCompleted handler.
Button {
    id: button
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignTop
    text: "Normal"
    implicitWidth: 100

    property bool __variationAvailable: button.variation !== undefined

    Component.onCompleted: {
        if (button.__variationAvailable)
            button.variation = Qt.binding(function() { return comboBox.currentIndex })
    }
}


Thanks a lot, this works (at least if I don't use a .ui.qml file that dosn't support js functions). I'm not fully satisfied about this method since it's a lot of code to add each time a user put a button in its app.
I will let the topic unsolved for a moment to see if someone else have a more compact and user friendly trick !

I just noticed that you used "undefined" as a string; shouldn't it be just undefined?

Yes, you are correct. Thanks, I've updated my answer.

You can simulate the binding by cloning the property and then reacting to the clone's property changed event:
QtObject {
    property int v: comboBox.currentIndex
    onVChanged: if ("variation" in button) button.variation = v
}

You can Try it Online!

with the same approach, I suppose that I could directly do this in the comboBox description : ComboBox { onCurrentIndexChanged: if ("variation" in button) button.variation = currentIndex }

Yes, but the above has been written in a way that you could componetize into a mock Binding like component if you wished it
